# Python3 Convert one INT to HEX

Tags: python, python-3.x, pack

```
def convert_output (output):
    return (struct.pack('i', output))

while True:
    pygame.event.pump()
    joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
    joystick.init()

    X_AX = int(joystick.get_axis(0) * 100)

    DATA = convert_output(X_AX)

    print("message:", (DATA), "----", hex(X_AX), "----", X_AX)
```

How can I get the same output in DATA as hex(X_AX)? 
I need X_AX as one byte HEX for UDP communication.

Current output looks like:

```
message: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00' ---- 0x0 ---- 0
message: b'\x18\x00\x00\x00' ---- 0x18 ---- 24
```

X_AX range is -100 to 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single byte representation, call `struct.pack` with format code `b` instead of `i`, and it will output a single signed byte (which can represent all values from -128 to 127 inclusive, handling the -100 to 100 range you require). The `repr` of said byte in the example case would be `b'\x18'` when `print`-ed, but when you `write` it to a socket or file in binary mode, the raw byte itself would be written.

See the [`struct` module's format code documentation for other options by size](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters).

Comment: thank you! sock.sendto((DATA), (HOST, PORT)) will send the raw byte?

Comment: @user3603948: Well, you could omit the parentheses around `DATA`, but yes, `sock.sendto(DATA, (host, port))` would be the normal approach for IPv4 (and IPv6 supports it, though [the `socket` docs indicate you should provide `flowinfo`, and `scopeid` for IPv6 addresses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-families)).